# How to get nested classes from a class from the parent one via Java Reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, inner-classes

Is it possible to get access to a nested class fields from the parent one via Java reflection ? I spent a lot of time reading the documentation and nothing really helped me.. Does anyone have an idea please ?

Comment: Can you provide example? nested classes are still just normal classes, you don't need to do anything special. You need instance of that nested class and Field that you want to access.

Comment: My problem is to get the instance of the nested Class,
I have a list of parent Classes that i have to have all their methods, constructors..ect and i would like to test if each class have a nested one in order to access to its Fields as well.

Comment: But you can't get value from non-static field if you don't have instance of that class. Otherwise you can just call `getDeclaredClasses` on parent class. tho in some corner cases this might not include all classes (classes generated at runtime, or injected in some other way)

Comment: The main problem is : is their a way to get an instance of the nested Class given an instance of the parent Class.

Comment: `Parent.class.getDeclaredClasses()` will give you all nested classes

Comment: Oh that easy ? Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the object of nested class like:

A.B obj = new A.B();

but your nested class should be static.